# How do I stop the following "External changes" message in Brackets

Tags: angularjs, adobe-brackets

I am using Brackets with Angular. When I Alt-Tab and come back to Brackets it presents me with the seemingly helpful message.

[image: Brackets message "External changes made"]

I would like to turn this off. I don't think it is the live preview feature because I still seem to get the message when I close the browser session which auto reload my files.

Regards

Comment: @Cleb he is asking for turning off of a feature. How can he show some code?

Comment: http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/project/FileSyncManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around it appears that this is indeed an issue in Brackets. What I suspect is happening in my case is that I have unsaved changes in my js file when I focus away from Brackets. When I return to Brackets the FileSyncManager in Brackets picks up that I might have changed the js file but it cant work out that it happened in Brackets or outside, so it safely displays the message, albeit slightly misleadingly. The issue is highlighted in github issue [ISSUE#10341](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10341)

I have not yet tried it but will install the [autosave extension](https://github.com/martypenner/brackets-autosave-files-on-window-blur) through the extensions manager in brackets to see if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I created an extension named “External changes dialog”.**

You can find it in available extensions directly in Brackets Editor, 
or here https://registry.brackets.io/ 
or here https://github.com/StarboyCZ/external-changes-dialog.

It automatically clicks on “Cancel” button in that “External changes” dialog.